# Convert RSpec 2 "to have().errors_on" matcher to RSpec 3

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

In my Gemfile

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.3'
```

I figured out, that the errors_on matcher moved to another gem: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers

I'm positive that there must a way to achieve the same within RSpec 3.

How can I convert the RSpec 2 have().errors_on matcher to RSpec 3?

```
  expect {
    click_button(I18n.t('helpers.submit.accounting.update'))
  }.to have(4).errors_on(:share_ksk, :central_office, :limit_value, :fix_disagio)
```

I tried:

```
  expect {
    click_button(I18n.t('helpers.submit.accounting.update'))
  }.to have_validation_error(I18n.t('accounting.two_digits_after_decimal_point')).on(
:share_ksk, 
:central_office, 
:limit_value, 
:fix_disagio)
```

regarding https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1033

but I get an RSpec error:

```
 undefined method `on' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x00000005913368>
```

Comment: I didn't know you could call the RSpec 2 matcher on a block.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
As you already know you can use `rspec-collection_matchers` gem.

Solution 2: You can monkey patch `errors_on` onto `::ActiveModel::Validations` as done [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/533660d10d2beeb586d99641c6b0cc280a642e05/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb#L33-L58)